# java.lang.NullPointerException and others. Extracting PhoneNumber from ListView.

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am new to android and java. I am trying to extract the phonenumber from the listview when clicked so as to send a SMS using that clicked Item on the ListView. I came up with java.lang.NullPointerException. Any idea what it means and how i am able to solve it? Thanks in advance!

LogCat

```
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at com.Elson.ProjectVersion.SendActivity$1.onItemClick(SendActivity.java:47)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at  android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at c    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-04 20:52:55.712: E/AndroidRuntime(21941):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SendActivity

```
package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SendActivity extends ListActivity {

Bundle savedInstanceState;
private ArrayList<Contacts> allContacts;
private Button AddContactsButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.send_layout);


    // get data from the App
    ContactsActivityApplication app = (ContactsActivityApplication) getApplication();
    allContacts = app.getAllContacts();

    // View --- Adapter ------ Data

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Contacts>(this, R.layout.history_row, R.id.textStart, allContacts));

    final ListView listView = this.getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Contacts selectedContax = (Contacts) listView.getSelectedItem();
            sendSMS(String.valueOf(selectedContax.getPhone()), "Hi");
        }
    }

    );
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SendActivity.class), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}

public void AddContactstoListClickHandler (View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterContactsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


private void setupViews()
{
AddContactsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnAddContactstoList);

}
}
```

Contacts

```
 package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;


public class Contacts implements Comparable<Contacts> {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String Phone;
    private int Email;
    private Date date;
    private double runningAverage;




    public Contacts(String name, String Phone,  Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.date = null;
    }

    public Contacts(long id, String name,String Phone) {
        this.id=id;
        this.Phone=Phone;
        this.name= (name);

    }


    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String Phone) {
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return null;
    }

    public long getDateEpoch(){
        return date.getTime()/1000;
    }
    public void setDateEpoch(long seconds){
        date= new Date (seconds*1000);
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }




    public void setRunningAverage(double runningAverage) {
        this.runningAverage = runningAverage;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object that){
        Contacts bs = (Contacts) that;

        return this.date.equals(bs.date);
      }


    @Override



    public String toString() {
        String result;

        if(date != null) {
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
            result = df.format(date) + "" + name + "" + Phone ; 
    }
    else {
          result = name + "" + Phone ; 
    }
        return result;
    }





    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contacts another) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NullPointerException` is triggered at this line:

```
sendSMS(String.valueOf(selectedContax.getPhone()), "Hi");
```

Therefore, either your `selectedContax` value is `null`, or its `phone` property is `null`.

Try adding a breakpoint here:

```
Contacts selectedContax = (Contacts) listView.getSelectedItem();
```

... and check which one is `null` in debug mode.

**Edit**

To prevent `selectedContax` from being `null`, replace this line:

```
Contacts selectedContax = (Contacts) listView.getSelectedItem();
```

... with this line:

```
Contacts selectedContax = (Contacts) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

There's no item *selected* by default because it's a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)!

Comment: @ErikPragt not really.

Comment: How do i check? I used the breakpoint and the line is green. There isn't any problem with it right?

Comment: @ElsonTan when the line is green, the execution paused at your breakpoint. You can either hover over the `selectedContax` reference to check whether it's `null` or not, or do the same by opening the *variables* tab in debug mode (I assume you use Eclipse). If `selectedContax` is `null` it might be that `allContacts = app.getAllContacts();` is not working (debug if it's empty), or you might have a problem with the adapter. Hopefully, your `selectedContax` variable isn't `null` but the `phone` property is.

Comment: @ElsonTan side-note: you will have to step-over the line with the breakpoint in order to get the value assigned to `selectedContax`. You do this in Eclipse by pressing F6 by default, once the execution paused at your breakpoint.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for ur detailed explanation. Now i understand. Ahh.. My selectedContax is null. I have checked the allContacts=app.getAllContacts(); It's working fine. So it is the adapter? I have reedited the post regarding the Adapter. I will try to fix but please do give suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible that public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { is wrong? I shouldn't use this?

Comment: HAHAHA. My friend help me and tried the same method before i see this too! IT WORKED! Hahahaha. Thanks a lot Mena! U taught me how to use the debug function and have such detailed explanation. Thanks for ur patience and guidance. Appreciate it from the bottom of my heart :)

Comment: Hey.. Just side track a bit and with pure curiosity. I wonder how you are so interested in programming languages like java? Is there a reason for it? Hahaha. Sorry for being random. :)

Comment: @ElsonTan glad to be of assistance :) Java is a great programming language and I've been working with it for years, hence the interest ;)

Comment: Sweet and simple reason. THANKS A LOT Once again. :)! Have a nice day!

Comment: Hey are u still there? I need help again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34800/discussion-between-mena-and-elson-tan)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your selectedContax is empty, that's why it's giving the NullpointerException. It's this line:

```
Contacts selectedContax = (Contacts) listView.getSelectedItem();
```

Which gets the [contax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contax), and this line which uses it:

```
sendSMS(String.valueOf(selectedContax.getPhone()), "Hi");
```

And the only reason why it can give a NPE, it because the selectedContax is null.

Comment: So any idea how i should declare my selectedContax?